# Why are two buttons showing up in my android application when I only declared one in the layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to get an app working, but when I declare one button in the layout, two buttons are showing up. They are appearing at the textviews and appearing in the top right corner. There are two buttons and I want one button on the bottom of the page.

Here is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.useprovider.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="listContacts"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/contactName"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_marginStart="63dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_marginEnd="63dp"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/contactID"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1" />
    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:id="@+id/contactID"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_marginStart="63dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_marginEnd="63dp"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_main"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_main"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_main"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/contactName"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is the java class that corresponds with the layout file:

```
package com.example.useprovider;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    final private int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 123;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                    REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        } else{
            ListContacts();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode
            , String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ListContacts();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
    protected void ListContacts(){
        Uri allContacts = Uri.parse("content://contacts/people");
        Cursor c;
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, allContacts, null, null, null, null);
        c = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
        int numberofrecords = c.getCount();
        System.out.println("number of contacts returned: "+numberofrecords);
        String[] columns = new String[]{
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID};
        int[] views = new int[]{R.id.contactName, R.id.contactID};
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.activity_main, c, columns, views,
                CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void listContacts(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ContactList.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: The button visible within the layout file needs to be constrained to a view or its parent otherwise its stuck in the corner. Set the constraints for the button then see if there are still two.

Comment: @KesWalker what are some examples for constraints that would be necessary?

Comment: I'm now getting zero buttons after applying  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@android:id/list"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/contactName"/>

Comment: @hippoman can you go into design mode of the layout so you can get a better understanding of how things are positioned?

Comment: you're a genius for that suggestion, but its still showing 2 buttons, one for each listview item, while in design mode it shows one button on the first list view item. After dragging the button to the bottom left corner, it sets absolute x and absolute y coordinates, but still shows the 2 buttons in the same positions as before.

Answer (score 0):

> `SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
>           adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
>                   this, R.layout.activity_main, c, columns, views,
>                   CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);`

You've defined the layout of your main activity as the layout the cursor adapter will use for creating the appearance of each item in the list.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[],%20int)

The result: The button as well as the text views will be replicated for each item in the list view. Your problem is not as simple as just having two buttons. For each contact you have, a button, a list view and 2 text views will be created whereas you only need 2 text views per contact.

A Simple Solution: Create a new XML file containing only the text views needed to display the contact name and id and provide it to the adapter as the layout.

List Item Layout:

```
//list_item.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Debug1ListItem">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/contactName" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Adapter Construction:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, R.layout.list_item, c, columns, views,
            CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
```